# JMeter does not run in windows 7(64 bit)

Tags: jmeter

I want to start using Jmeter for performance testing but I am unable to run it on my system.

When I click on Jmeter.bat, command prompt opens for a fraction and then gets closed.I already set path of java.I am using java version 1.8.0_75.

The error I'm getting is:

```
java.lang.Throwable: could not access C:\Users\hp\Desktop\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\lib\ext
     at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.<clinit><NewDriver.java:99>
```

Comment: Open windows command line (type `cmd` in run), go to jmeter/bin folder and run jmeter.bat. Come back and post your error message.

Comment: And please post the error message as text, not as a screenshot

Comment: java.lang.Throwable: could not access C:\Users\hp\Desktop\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\lib\ext    at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.<clinit><NewDriver.java:99>

Comment: java.lang.Throwable: could not access C:\Users\hp\Desktop\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\lib\ext at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.<clinit><NewDriver.java:99> @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: The error says it all really. You're either missing permissions or missing the folder.

Answer (score 0):

The JAR file can be corrupted. Try to re-download from

- https://www.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/